# Why is my xcode jump to assembly view when break point set?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, ios5, breakpoints

When I try to debug with breakpoint, it jump to assembly view like this no matter which line of code. I want the highlight of current source line back!!

How can I config it??

[image]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is a useful feature sometimes, but is easy to turn off:

`Debug > Debug Workflow > Always Show Disassembly`

In older versions of Xcode (<6.1):

`Product > Debug Workflow > Show Disassembly When Debugging`

Comment: does not work for me! keeps showing lines and lines of assembly!!

Comment: That's strange @Patrick, it still works for me...
If you figure out what's going on for you, let us know in a comment/answer - others might be experiencing the same thing!

Comment: where is product in ms visual 2005?

Comment: `Debug > Debug Workflow > Always Show Disassembly` in XCode 6.1

Comment: same is with XCode 8.3

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue in Xcode 6.1 and solved it by doing the following:

Debug -> Debug Workflow -> UNCHECK Always Show Disassembly

Make sure "Always Show Disassembly" is unchecked

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Product > Debug > Create Symbolic Breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

I agree with humphriesj regarding "Always Show Disassembly" in Xcode 6.1, and it did work for awhile.

But for me it seems to have **turned itself back on,** even though **it was still unchecked** in the menu. I turned it on and then back off, and finally I can see the source code again.