# Xcode is not stopping at break point

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I placed break point inside the function but its not stopping at same point.

Its point thread Queue:
I do not understand what this  assembly level or "Micro processor" language stating to me.

[image]

How can I redirect this to the debug point.

Comment: Did you add break point in some Library function ?

Comment: @JonSnow I add only one break point in side Objective-c controller class i.e., "MSProfileViewController" which i created for the project

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12090965/4601900

Comment: Did you close and reopen the Xcode?

Comment: Did you Clean Build Folder / Rebuild?

Comment: @JonSnow Thanks its really help! uncheck always show disassembly from debug its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

- Uncheck **Always Show Disassembly** under Xcode Debug menu
- Else try restarting your Xcode

[image]

Hope that helps !